# qbs QML debugging doesn't work

Tags: qt, qml, qbs

After migration to QBS my QML debugging stopped working.

I made sure that:

1. I'm building a debug build, C++ debugging works
2. I've checked "Enable QML Debugging" in qt creator's Project tab
3. I've even tried to add qbs properties manually `Qt.declarative.qmlDebugging:true Qt.quick.qmlDebugging:true`

Still QtCreator says:

> Some breakpoints cannot be handled by the debugger languages currently active, and will be ignored.

QML debugging works with an old .pro

My system:

- Linux archlinux 4.15.7-1-ARCH
- QBS 1.10.1
- Qt 5.10.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so clear, but there are **TWO** checkboxes.
One at the build step, and another one in the run step.

So to get QML Debugging working you have to check both of them.

I missed the one under the "Projects->Run->Debugger settings->Enable QML"

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming 4.6 release of Qt Creator should be smarter about this and auto-enable the checkbox in the run settings if the one in the build settings gets enabled.